# QGIS 3.10: attribute form showing foreign key instead of referencing field

Tags: qgis-3, attribute-table

In a QGIS 3.10 project, I've set up a relationship between two postgis table. In postgis, table **A** has two unique fields: "id" and "name". "Id" is the primary key but "name" is used as a foreign key for table **B** as "name A".

In the QGIS project's properties, I've set up the relation as so:
Parent layer: layer **A**
Referenced field: Name
Child Layer: layer **B**
Referencing field: Name A

This works as expected, I can then create attribute form for both layers, with the form of layer **A** having a section for showing layer **B**'s attribute form.

However, I noticed that when I open a the attribute table of layer **B**, the field which should be showing "name A" is instead showing the "Id" field of layer **A**.

How can I set up the layer B form so that it shows "name A" as expected? (note I do not have this"error" in Postgis when i check the database in PgAdmin). Maybe I should set up a "reverse" relationship in QGIS?

Answer (score 1):

OK, found the solution myself and posting it here for reference:

In the layer B properties, attribute form: selecting the "Name A" field will now bring new options for displaying data, including a new option in "Reference relation" tool: "Display Expression". There the field from table A to be displayed can be selected in the drop-down menu.